# Difference between baseline and baselineOnMigrate in flyway?

Tags: java, flyway

I am using flyway for the first time. I tried to use it in my java swing desktop application. I tried to use it in my project that have existing database. It shows an error

> Found non-empty schema(s) `schema_name` without schema history table! Use
>   baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema
>   history table.

I tried to read some documentation but I can't get simple comparison between the both. Please help me to find the difference and which one I can use in this situation. I am using Java API of flyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`baseline()` is a method you can call on Flyway. You can invoke it from command line, for example:

```
flyway baseline
```

On the other hand, `baselineOnMigrate` is a setting which you can set int Flyway configuration (if you're using SpringBoot it's `application.properties`):

```
flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true
```

It means "if schema is non-empty and user didn't call `flyway baseline` explicitly, call it implicitly now"

Comment: I am using flyway java api, and in that, flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true) and flyway.baseline() exist

Comment: One explicitly creates baseline, the other does it implicitly.